# how to use custom package that is run on python3.5.1. I want to use in a project which is running on python2.7

Tags: python

My problem is,

created one custom package that is run on python3.5.1.
I want to use in a project which is running on python2.7.

how to use python 3.x version installed packages into python2.x version file.

for example:
file1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.x

import pkg1  (pkg1 depends on python3)
```

I tried with sys.path.append to add python3/sitepackages into python2 sys.path
but also I didn't import pkg1.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)

Comment: Short answer: don't do that!